# Where does WhatsApp store thumbnails of media in Android phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, thumbnails

Today, I was observing WhatsApp app behavior.

By using a camera, I took a photo. That photo got stored in the camera directory of my cell phone (obviously that is normal behavior). And after that, I shared the same photo to one of my contacts using WhatsApp. After sharing, I deleted that photo from the camera directory and checked my WhatsApp contact (to whom I shared the photo) it was still in the list of messages.

Then I found on Google that WhatsApp also stores sent images in the internal directory as well. Then I deleted the same photo from WhatsApp's internal memory and checked the WhatsApp contact (to whom I shared the photo), I found that there was no real photo but a blurry image of the same photo was there (that is called thumbnail).

I tried to find out where it was getting that thumbnail. I searched my whole cell phone directory or even WhatsApp media directory as well, but could not find the thumbnail.

My question is, what is the location in the cell where WhatsApp stores the thumbnails? I am assuming that WhatsApp keeps the thumbnail URL and downloads on demand. Is that right? Any help?

Comment: I guess the thumbnail is stored in the database itself as a blob, which is at `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db`

Comment: I can see them here `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/files/photos/`. You can verify

Answer (score 2):

WhatsApp stores the thumbnail as `BLOB` in the database in `message_thumbnails` table under `thumbnail` column.

Comment: this is correct. For anyone wanting to populate a iOS->Android sqlite db with thumbnails, its `insert into message_thumbnails (thumbnail, key_remote_jid, key_id) values (x'<hexstring>, '123456789-123456789@g.us', '2AD6F9891DFF121C126D'););`

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to Explorer/file manager of your mobile, and scroll down to the `WhatsApp` folder.
2. Open it and go to `WhatsApp Media`.
3. Activate the `Show hidden files` option (usually a 3-dot symbol at the top-right corner).
4. Open the `.sent` folder.
5. Search for your photo.

Comment: This is NOT correct, thumbnails are NOT stored in "whatsapp images\.sent" folder

Answer (score -2):

Check the *thumbnails* table in the database at */data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db*.